# Including two different maps in one QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

How do I use print composer in QGIS 2.0.1 to produce a final product with two different maps on the same sheet?

I can't figure out how to use the 'add a map' button to add anything other than a duplicate copy of what I already have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this at the moment is via the "lock layers for map item" check box in the map item's properties. This allows you to restrict which layers are visible in each map item. So, basically, you set up the map canvas how you'd like for one map, then check its lock layers check box. Then switch back to the canvas and set up the layers for the second map and repeat. It's not ideal, but generally works OK. 
There's also an alternative method for styling, which is to use the $map variable and data defined or rule based symbology. This process is described here: 
 http://nyalldawson.net/2014/01/qgis-two-neat-features-in-2-2/