# Plotting two Maps on one sheet in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, printing

I am trying to put two different maps on one sheet, one of them should show the raster image of a survey, the other one the vector-rendering of anomalies of the same area, but without the raster image.

This worked in the editor by just not updating one of the mapframes, but when I save the plan as an image QGIS automatically updates both frames, so they both show the same image.

Does anyone know, how to avoid this?

I am using QGIS 2.8.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including two different maps in one QGIS Print Composer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93436/including-two-different-maps-in-one-qgis-print-composer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually lock the map I want to prevent from updating automatically, using the option **'Lock layers for map item'** within map properties in QGIS composer:

1. In the canvas: check the layer(s) you need to display
2. In the composer: create a new map and check the option 'Lock layers for map item' in the element's properties (see screenshot below)
3. Back in the canvas: check the layer(s) you need to display in your second map
4. Back in the composer: create another map. The first map shouldn't follow the canvas changes.

[image]

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried this, but it didn't work. I suppose this might be a bug? I mean, it should work when I lock the maps, shouldn't it?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the right option. Sorry I had not tested on my QGIS and the answer I initially gave did not do the job (not a bug, therefore...).

Comment: This worked. (For later readers: Just tick "Lock layers for map" to lock the map).

Thanks a lot!